# Real numbers $x,y$ satisfies $x^2+y^2=1.$If the minimum and maximum value of the expression $z=\frac{4-y}{7-x}$ are $m$ and $M$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, circles

Real numbers $x,y$ satisfies $x^2+y^2=1.$If the minimum and maximum value of the expression $z=\frac{4-y}{7-x}$ are $m$ and $M$ respectively,then find $2M+6m.$

---

Let $x=\cos\theta$ and $y=\sin\theta$,because $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$.
Then we need to find the minimum and maximum value of the expression $\frac{4-\sin\theta}{7-\cos\theta}$.
I differentiated it and equated it to zero to find the critical points or points of extrema.
They are $\theta_1=\arcsin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{65}})-\arctan(\frac{7}{4})$ and $\theta_2=\arccos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{65}})+\arctan(\frac{4}{7})$
I found $\frac{4-\sin\theta_1}{7-\cos\theta_1}$ and $\frac{4-\sin\theta_2}{7-\cos\theta_2}$.
$\frac{4-\sin\theta_1}{7-\cos\theta_1}=\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{4-\sin\theta_2}{7-\cos\theta_2}=\frac{5}{12}$
This method is full of lengthy calculations.I want to know is there an elegant solution possible for this problem which is short and easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$y-4=z(x-7)\tag{1}$$
is an equation of all the lines that pass $(7,4)$ with slope $z$. When $z$ is at its minimum or maximum then the line touches the unit circle. Equation of tangent lines with slope $z$ to a unit circle is
$$y=zx\pm\sqrt{z^2+1}\tag{2}$$
Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$-7z+4=\pm\sqrt{z^2+1}$$
$$(7z-4)^2=z^2+1$$
$$48z^2-56z+15=0$$
$$(4z-3)(12z-5)=0$$
$$\therefore M=\frac34, m=\frac5{12}$$

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Let $\dfrac{4-\sin \theta}{7-\cos \theta}=u$

Use Weierstrass Substitution $t=\tan\dfrac\theta2$ to form a Quadratic Equation in $t$ on rearrangement.

As $t$ is real, the discriminant must be non-negative

Comment: Both methods are elegant,i chose the above one because in my book,this question was given under circles chapter and the above solution uses the property of circles and tangents to solve it.+1 for your solution.@labbhattacharjee.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\displaystyle k=\frac{4-y}{7-x}\Rightarrow 7k-kx=4-y\Rightarrow kx-y = 7k-4$ and given $x^2+y^2=1$

Now using the **Cauchy-Schwarz inequality**, we get $$[k^2+(-1)^2](x^2+y^2)\geq (kx-y)^2$$

So $$k^2+1\geq (7k-4)^2\Rightarrow 49k^2+16-56k\leq k^2+1$$

So $$48k^2-56k+15\leq 0\Rightarrow (4k-3)(12k-5)\leq 0$$

So we get $\displaystyle \frac{5}{12}\leq k\leq \frac{3}{4}$